# capture click of Facebook 'Like' button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-like

I am looking on the [Facebook Developers Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) to locate some sample code that would allow me to capture a click event on the "Like" button. It states:

> If you are using the XFBML version of the button, you can subscribe to
>   the 'edge.create' event through FB.Event.subscribe.

I am not using XFBML however, this is my code:

```
<div class="social_net_button facebook_button">
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>(function(d, s, id) {
              var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
              if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
              js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
              js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
              fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

              FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
                     function(response) {
                          alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
                     }
              );

            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
      <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Ayrshire-Minis/160330240663397" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="70" data-show-faces="false" data-action="recommend"></div>
    </div>
```

Can a click of the 'Like' button be captured by jQuery?

Comment: So, why are you not using XFBML? You can find the click event on the iframe(although, I never I tried this) but not on the button in the iframe. So you're dependent on the code Facebook provides.

Comment: _“I am not using XFBML however”_ – oh but yes, you are ;-) – `<div class="fb-like"…` is just what FB calls the “HTML5-compliant markup” version of XFBML.

Comment: Great to know that CBroe, thanks. I already thought it was odd since both methods include the same JS.

Comment: @CBroe Regardless of whether the user increments the like counter I would like to track if a user has clicked the Recommend/Like button, but the code below provided by Robin does not work. I have had a look around and you would imagine it is a fairly simple thing to do, not to mention common, but I can't find a solution to this. Is the problem in my implementation?

Comment: @ReneGeuze I have updated the code with an attempt to capture the like, but for some reason it still cannot access the `FB`. Where is this being loaded from and where should this code be placed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution, it would appear, is sending the request asynchronously. This code below works when placed after my `fb-like` div class:

```
     <script>
           window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                   FB.init({
                                           status: true, // check login status
                                           cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                                           xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
                                   });
           };
     </script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
           window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
             FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
                     function(response) {
                           _gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'facebook', 'like', document.location.href]);
                     }
             );
           };
     </script>
```

Comment: I'll remove my acceptance of my answer here as this seems to be working intermittently. I am very surprised that Facebook don't document this properly.

Answer (score 5):

You could try this.

http://jsfiddle.net/qkyAe/

Docs: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
    console.log('clicked');
});​
```

I think this one only counts if user clicks AND it increaes the like count (logged in users only) Since I don't have an FB-Account I couldn't try it.
Please tell me, if it works :)

Update:

The FB object comes from the script you're already embedding.

Comment: Yes, I had came across that code before, however is there a way to track the click without the like count being increased? It wasn't liking the reference to `FB`.

Comment: Since it's in an iFrame, I think you can't. But maybe someone else can prove me wrong.

Comment: The code in your jsFiddle doesn't seem to work. I'm not certain what is wrong with it, n maybe it can't see the `FB`?

Answer (score 2):

This code REALLY works :)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.addEvent('load', function() {
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: '42424242424242',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
    });
};
(function(d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk';
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement('script');
    js.id = id;
    js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));
});//]]>  

</script>


         <div id="fb-root"></div> 
         <div class="box">
             <p>First a Like Box of a facebook page</p>
             <p class="info">edge.create is not called</p>
             <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/jsfiddle" data-width="292" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="false" data-header="true"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="box">
             <p>Like Button of a website</p>
             <p class="info">here you can see the edge.create fire</p>
             <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://jsfiddle.net" data-send="false" data-width="150" data-show-faces="true"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="box">
             <p>Like Button of a Facebook Page</p>
             <p class="info">here you can see the edge.create fire</p>
             <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/jsfiddle" data-send="false" data-width="150" data-show-faces="true"></div>
         </div>
         <div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create')` call is right after the init (within the `window.fbAsyncInit` function and not outside of it)

**Example**

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    /* Additional initialization code here
    ******************************************************/
};
```

...then load the SDK Asynchronously!